# Asymptotics for the number of triangulations of a manifold M

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, simplicial-stuff

In [Gromov's talk at the Clay Math Research](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5DLpAqX4YA&feature=BFa&list=PL0767A09CF0864F8A&lf=plpp_video) from 23:23 to 25:55 Gromov says (slightly paraphrased)

> I want to emphasize a problem which
>   comes from mathematical physics which
>   is unsolved which is indicating that
>   we don't understanding what
>   triangulation is. And the problem is
>   extremely simple. You take a manifold,
>   and you just ask how many
>   triangulations it has with a given
>   number of simplices. So you have your
>   manifold $X$ and you have the number
>   of triangulations with k simplices
>   $N_k(X)$ and you want to know what
>   happens to it as $k$ goes to infinity,
>   roughly. You take triangulations up to
>   isomorphism. It's bounded below by $(1 + \epsilon)^k$ and it's bounded from above by $k^k$, roughly. That's kind
>   of trivial, you just keep subdividing
>   and you see how many automorphisms you
>   have on a $k$ element set. The
>   question is, where is the truth?  And
>   nothing is known, just absolutely
>   blank. For surfaces you know, it's
>   like that [exponential] and physicists
>   kind of made that computation.
>
> [...]
>
> The whole point is that the manifold
>   must be fixed, if you vary the
>   manifold you would have $k^k$.
>
> The subtle point is fix a topological
>   manifold, how does the combinatorics
>   tell you something about the topology.
>   We think we understand it, but when we
>   do this problem we don't. There's
>   absolutely not a direct link between
>   the two. We have a zero level question
>   in topology, we cannot answer it.

The introduction to Kontsevich's thesis *Intersection theory on the moduli space of curves and the matrix Airy function* gives references to the solution to the problem for closed surfaces. Are there any other papers in the literature that discuss this problem?

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/87393/are-there-lots-of-integer-homology-three-spheres and http://ldtopology.wordpress.com/2012/02/05/2306/ for some recent discussion

Comment: Ben Burton works on this problem.  I think he's pretty convinced that even for spheres, the growth-rate is super-exponential. He certainly has numerical evidence but I suspect he might eventually have a proof.  

Comment: Following up on Ryan's pointer, Burton's paper "The Pachner graph and the simplification of 3-sphere triangulations" (http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.4169) includes an algorithm for "isomorph-free generation of all 3-manifold triangulations of a given size."

Comment: A related result is due to Gil Kalai. He showed that the number of triangulated manifolds (of any dimension) with $n$ labelled vertices is $2^{2^{.69424\cdots n(1+o(1))}}$. See http://www.springerlink.com/content/78044667x381777g/.

Comment: @Richard: does this mean triangulations which are manifolds, or DISTINCT (topologically) manifolds?
